# What do you call a linear operator whose image is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

I was just curious, is there any specific name for linear operators $T: X \rightarrow Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are normed linear spaces, whose image is bounded? (In the sense that there exists $M > 0$ such that $||Tx||_Y \leq M$ for every $x \in X$.)

This was how I initially thought how bounded operators must be defined as, until I saw the actual definition.

Comment: The zero operator?

Comment: That implies $Tx=0$ for all $x$ You call $T$ the zero oeprator :-).

Comment: The image of a non-zero operator is at least a line, which has infinite extent and is unbounded.

Comment: Oh okay. Stupid me... Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If such an operator exists it is trivial. Indeed, suppose $v\in T(X)$ is non-zero. Then $v=Tu$ for some $u\in X$. Furthermore $\alpha v=T\alpha u$ for all $\alpha\in \mathbb R$. Thus $\alpha v\in T(X)$ for all $\alpha$, but $\|\alpha v\|\to \infty$ as $\alpha\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in X$ and suppose that $Tx \ne 0.$ We can assume that $||Tx||_Y=1.$  For $n \in \mathbb N$ we have

$$ n=||T(nx)||_Y \le M.$$

Since this holds for all $n$ we get a contradiction. Thus $Tx=0$. Since $x \in X$ was arbitrary, $T=0.$